# Using Phonegap/Cordova JS App and MS ADAL JS. How to redirect URI in real mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, adal, devextreme

I'm developing a webapp using Phonegap/Cordova, and for authentication: Adal.js (Active Directory Authentication Library for JavaScript). Using DevExtreme Components to UI.

On the Browser Simulator it works fine, but when I generate .apk and install on android mobile device, doesn't works. The problem is Redirect Uri, in Azure Portal -> App Registrations, I configure reply url: `https:localhost:port/index.html`, but in android app (in this case cordova app) I need to configure it to something like: `file://android_asset/index.html`. But doesn't works.

Is there any way to make it work?

```
var microsoftAuthenticationParameters = {
        clientId: "myClientID",
        tenantId: "myTenantID",
        popUp: true,
        redirectUri: window.location.href + '/index.html',
        endpoints: { "aisApiUri": "myClientID" },
        cacheLocation: "localStorage"
    }

    function authenticate() {

        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(microsoftAuthenticationParameters);

        var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
        if (isCallback) {
            authContext.handleWindowCallback();
        }

        if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
            window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
        }
        else {
            authContext.getLoginError();
        }

        var user = authContext.getCachedUser();

        if (user) {
            userInfo = user.userName;
            var username = userInfo.split("@");            
        }
        else {
            authContext.login();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADAL is not designed to work in Cordova. However, there is a Cordova plugin that you can use for setting up AAD authentication. Reference: [Azure ADAL Authentication for Cordova App Guidance](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cordova-docs/blob/master/articles/app-services/add-authentication.md) Also, I would suggest that you check the steps mentioned in the below document for adding authentication to your Cordova Application. [Add Authentication to the App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users)

There are some good workarounds provided here on Stackoverflow for the very problem you described, and some helpful samples on Github as well. [Setting a valid Azure AD uri for PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842033/setting-a-valid-azure-ad-uri-for-phonegap?rq=1)